# WebRTC Never Stream Video

Tags: c++, google-chrome, webrtc

I have a website that recieves WEBRTC from my mobileApp very well.

A new C++ module that I develop that should send video using WEBRTC to the same website is not working and I failed to know why.

**NOT WORKING** FILES:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-6ZsfcQztexAspYWB4Nzvgf2e0-0C8vC

**WORKING** FILE:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bL_WOW6L1mGCXQC6HT6a14Sa58hOIcAh

kindly advise. I am stuck.

Comment: Another thing is that in the above sample I used an empty IceServer array, as when I use non empty array the connection is not completed at all and pauses in ice gathering. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-wmyMYeEM-hP_Ie2G4pGWtgzRpoD2a7H    ... BTW in both cases the android mobile app works file !!!

Comment: I tried webrtc branch head 72 and again the same behaviour

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED AT LAST:
the issue mainly was due mDNS that is activated on chrome but gives "network unreachable" from my code.
*the main problem was due to mDNS that chrome activates by default while webrtc need a lib called libnice v>0.1.14 which is the current stable release to resolve local addresses.*

second peerConnectionFactory init:
I had to pass threads parameter. not this  but also I had to init the network thread differently.
    g_worker_thread = rtc::Thread::Create();

```
g_worker_thread->Start();

g_signaling_thread = rtc::Thread::Create();

g_signaling_thread->Start();

g_networking_thread = **rtc::Thread::CreateWithSocketServer();**

g_networking_thread->Start();
```

I am not sure what is the reason of the second point but maybe because I initiate webrtc from my main function in c and not through a thread.

Anyway I hope this helps someone... I was stuck for two weeks to solve it.